# UITableView source to different objects

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uikit

A `UITableView` object requires 2 other objects to be useful: a `delegate` and a `data source` 
(specifically, objects that adhere to the `UITableViewDelegate` and 
`UITableViewDataSource` protocols).
In which cases an application might switch a `UITableView` object’s data 
source to a different object during the runtime of the application?

Answer (score 0):

You can change data source whenever you want, just call `-reloadData` after doing it.

Here is some useful information about separating out data source: http://www.objc.io/issue-1/lighter-view-controllers.html